# Handle null in reflection

Tags: c#, system.reflection

How to handle null value for the non-static method which returns property value with count i.e. When we have propertyName and there is no value set for this property

```
public object Property(propertyName)
{
    return car.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(car, null);
}
```

Different approaches I tried:

First approach:

```
public object Property(propertyName)
{
    return (car.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(car, null)).Value;
}
```

This didn't work for me.

Second approach:

```
public object Property(propertyName)
{
    var value = car.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(car, null);
    if (value != null)
        return  value;
    else
        return value;
}
```

How this can be achieved? None of the above approaches worked for me.

Comment: Your question is currently very unclear. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ - and edit your question carefully, paying particular attention to the formatting. (I've removed the worst aspects of the original formatting, but basically just look at the preview and ask if that's a question *you'd* want to answer.)

Comment: What's `propertyName`?  a string?  If so, it should say `public object Property(string propertyName)`.

Comment: Yes it is public object Property (string propertyName)

Comment: `if (anything_at_all) return value; else return value;`  Logically simplifies to just `return value` with no `if`.  So I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.  What are you expecting to be `null` in your situation?

Comment: Do you mean if `propertyName` is not a property of the object?  (`GetProperty` will return a null `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`, so you'll have to check for that before proceeding to call `.GetValue` on it.

Comment: what If we have propertyName but the GetValue of property is null. Getting exception.

Comment: You shouldn't get an exception when getting the value of a property when the value is null.  But if you get a property that completely doesn't exist and you just access .GetValue of the null PropertyInfo, you'll get an exception.  If you're getting an exception please post the *exact* text of the exception in your question.  (That's just good question asking, to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that shows how to handle a null value coming back from a property.

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get { return "Honda"; } }
    public string SomethingNull { get { return null; } }
}

public class Foo
{
    object car = new Car();

    public object Property(string propertyName)
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = car.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (property == null) {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Property {0} doesn't exist", propertyName));
        }

        return property.GetValue(car, null);
    }
}

class Program
{

    public static void Demo(Foo foo, string propertyName)
    {
        object propertyValue = foo.Property(propertyName);
        if (propertyValue == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The property {0} value is null", propertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The property {0} value is not null and its value is {1}", propertyName, propertyValue);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Demo(foo, "Name");
        Demo(foo, "SomethingNull");
        try
        {
            Demo(foo, "ThisDoesNotExist");
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am asking what If we have propertyName but the GetValue of property is null. How to handle this scenario

Comment: @Ashwin, does this match your question now?

Comment: Yes Wyck this is my question. Thanks for the efforts you put in this.

Comment: Would it help to see how to handle a non-existent property too?  (I added that too in an edit.)

Comment: In actual code, property name are fetched from Database that by stored procedure call and storing them in List of strings.

Comment: @Ashwin Does this answer your question?  Accept the answer or up-vote as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wyck

Answer (score 0):

return car.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(car, null);
}

That's to allow null value of propertyName if it's property is not set then we can use Null condition.